# What does "Network" inside yammer refer to? is it similar to "Everyone except external" sharepoint group

Tags: office-365, external-users, yammer

When creating new yammer groups we got 2 options, "Internal" & "External" groups as follow:-

[image]

and inside the Internal group >> we got a text saying that anyone inside your network can view conversations. so what does the word "network" refer to? does it refer to all internal users inside office 365 (similar to "Everyone except external" sharepoint group)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, this is similar to "Everyone except external users" SharePoint group. Although this group can have members, but it's content will be visible to all users from your organization and they can post content even though they are not members of the Group.

Similar will happen if you have Office 365 connected SharePoint site, "Everyone except external users" SharePoint group will be added in the site's 'Contributor' group.